# Catch response on send_keys

Tags: python, selenium, python-unittest

I am using Selenium and unittest to write automated testing for web app

I have a text field that works as a 'search engine'. API returns response in json format on the entry of each character in the text field.

For example I get element of search and enter “Arrays” in the same:

```
 def test_search(self):
    driver = self.driver
    driver.get(URL)
    # find text field
    element = driver.find_element_by_id("gsc-i-id2")
    #  enter some text into a text field
    element.send_keys("Arrays")
    # --> api returns response in json format
    # --> catch response
```

[image]

Is it posible to get result list? Idea is to get JSON from response, is it possible?

Comment: I believe this is possible, but since you didn't share minimal reproducible details we have nothing to do with this question

Comment: Are you asking about the API response in JSON format or results displayed on GUI as you presenting on your screenshot? Also, since it is a GeeksforGeeks, why don't you share the url in your code?